# Google Maps APIv2 Implementation

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi guys I've been try to implement the following into my app.
A page which shows your location on Google maps and have following tutorials but every time i run this section of my app it crashes help would be very much appreciated
Thank You

It always crashes when ran on my device i've tried so many thing but alas im a beginner at android
The Place section which will just show you where you are on the map and you co-ordinates doesnt seem to work for me at all.

Here's the log cat.

**Log Cat**

```
04-02 03:45:19.025: W/dalvikvm(1102): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a71930)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activityComponentInfo{com.hangoverhelper/com.hangoverhelper.Place}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at com.hangoverhelper.Place.onCreate(Place.java:42)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-02 03:45:19.104: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     ... 11 more
```

**Place.java**

```
package com.hangoverhelper;
import com.hangoverhelper.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Place extends Activity 
        implements LocationSource, LocationListener{

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;
    TextView tvLocInfo;

    LocationManager myLocationManager = null;
    OnLocationChangedListener myLocationListener = null;
    Criteria myCriteria;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);
        tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment myMapFragment 
            = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        myCriteria = new Criteria();
        myCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.place, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.menu_legalnotices) {
            String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                    getApplicationContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Place.this);
            LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
            LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
            LicenseDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Register for location updates using a Criteria, and a callback on the specified looper thread.
            myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    0L,             //minTime
                    0.0f,           //minDistance
                    myCriteria,     //criteria
                    this,           //listener
                    null);          //looper

            //Replaces the location source of the my-location layer.
            myMap.setLocationSource(this);

        }else{
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);    
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        myMap.setLocationSource(null);
        myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
        myLocationListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        myLocationListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (myLocationListener != null) {
            myLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();

            tvLocInfo.setText(
                    "lat: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "lon: " + lon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

## *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hangoverhelper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.hangoverhelper.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.hangoverhelper.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.Place"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/local_title"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.Pill"
            android:label="@string/pills_title" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.Food"
            android:label="@string/food_title" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.Coffee"
            android:label="@string/coffee_title" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.hangoverhelper.Home"
            android:label="@string/home_title" >
        </activity>
      <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBkFR4cjuUf2rw8MfLBrWS8iaS2-Th5XA4"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## activity_place.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Place" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/custom_info_contents" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#A0FFFFFF" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/local" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The crash comes from the line 42 of your Place class

Comment: check kine number 42 in Place.java file.there is NP.

Answer (score 0):

Your map activity should extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity Replace `public class Place extends Activity` by **`public class Place extends FragmentActivity`**